# Script help to trigger IMPORTXML formula once a day in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

**CURRENT WORKAROUND -** A Google Sheet with thousands of rows pulling data through the IMPORTXML formula at the standard rate, this causes the sheet to both slow down other functions and some cells are stuck in the 'loading...' state.

**HELP NEEDED -**
I'd like to have a script that runs the IMPORTXML formula once a day/week and populates these cells until next time it is triggered. A button to trigger the formula is okay, it would have to be located in 'Database Stats' and run the formula in 'Database', due to space issues in the LIVE sheet.

I have zero knowledge in programming or writing scripts, so any help is appreciated here.

**SAMPLE SHEET -**
I have setup a dummy sheet that is populated with 200 Twitch Channel names in column A, the IMPORTXML formula pulls data into column E.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PXHAZfbF7x7QQXYMJ7RoRQDEwocWVU22CxFms-9OMlE/edit?usp=sharing

**FORMULA -** It pulls the Average Viewership over 30 days from the Twitch Channel in column A. Data is sourced from [Sullygnome](https://sullygnome.com/) which uses the Twitch API and updates ~daily.

Thank you in advance to any help and support on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```
function refreshFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var range = sheet.getRange('E2:E'); 
  var getFormulas = range.getFormulas();
  var setFormulas = range.setFormulas(getFormulas); 
}
```

What I did here is to get the existing formula in your Column `E2:E` using `getFormulas()` and to set it back to the same Column `E2:E`, I used `setFormulas()`. This will refresh the **IMPORTXML formula** once the script is executed.

---

### Steps to Add Trigger

1. From your Apps Script project.
2. At the left, click **Triggers**
3. At the bottom right, click **Add Trigger**.
4. You can follow the image below for the trigger configuration.
   Note: What I set here is daily trigger but if you prefer weekly, you can
   simply change the `Select type of time based trigger` to `Week timer`

[image]

For your reference: [Manage triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually)

---

### Steps to Add Button

1. Insert an image or drawing by selecting **Insert** > **Image** or **Insert** > **Drawing**.
2. After inserting the image or drawing, click it. A small drop-down menu selector appears in the top right-hand corner. Click it and choose **Assign script**.
3. In the dialog box that appears, enter `refreshFormula` (this is the Apps Script function that I used). Click **OK**.
4. Click the **image** or **drawing** again and the function should execute.

Here's a sample button that I created:

[image]

**Reference**: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in

---

I have added the steps for the two options that you're considering to use, so feel free to follow which option would work best for you. I hope this helps!

**References:**

- [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help with this @cnavar!  
  
To confirm, I implemented the Script & Trigger solution. Currently monitoring to make sure it does what it is intended to do, hoping the formula doesn't run by itself every couple hours.  
  
I'll keep you updated! :)

Comment: Hello! I've been monitoring the database today and have noticed that the formula is still running multiple times a day because the top 50-100 Creators currently have the dreaded "loading..." when too many IMPORTXML requests.